# Template strings with Cypress and Mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, cypress

I am using cypress and Mocha.
I want to do some templating with mocha so that I can run the same test with the different data set. But template strings don't work for some reason in combination with Cypress and Mocha.
This is what I have:

```
import { CheckoutActions } from '../support/actions/common/checkout-actions';
import { CheckoutActionsCats } from '../support/actions/cats/checkout-actions';

export interface VoucherTestData {
  ctx: string;
  checkoutActions: CheckoutActions;
}

let dataSet: VoucherTestData[] = [
  {
    ctx: ' cats',
    checkoutActions: new CheckoutActionsCats(),
  },
];

dataSet.forEach(function (data) {
  context(`${data.ctx}`, function () {
    console.log('Context data.ctx');
    console.log(data.ctx); // Prints cats
    if (data.ctx === 'cats') {
      console.log('Data is cats');
    } else {
      console.log('Data failed'); // This is printed. Why?
    }
    const env = Cypress.env('dataEnv');

    beforeEach(function () {
      console.log('beforeEach data.ctx');
      console.log(data.ctx); // Prints cats
      cy.fixture(env + '/users').as('users'); // users is a JSON file
      cy.fixture(env + '/products').as('products'); // products is a JSON file
      cy.fixture(env + '/vouchers').as('vouchers'); // vouchers is a JSON file
    });

    describe('My suite', function () {
      beforeEach(function () {
        console.log('Suite');
        console.log(`${data.ctx}`); // Prints cats
        this.url = Cypress.env(`${data.ctx}Baseurl`); // This is undefined. If I use Cypress.env('cats'); then it works
        this.product = this.products[`${data.ctx}`]; // This is undefined. If I put this.products['cats'] than it is ok
        this.testVoucher = this.vouchers[`${data.ctx}`].voucher; // Error "Cannot read property 'voucher' of undefined". 
        // If i put this.vouchers['cats'].voucher than it is ok
      });
      it('should do something', function () {
        cy.log(this.url); // Prints undefined. Why?
        cy.log(data.ctx); // Prints cats
        cy.log(this.product.standardProduct);
        cy.log(this.testVoucher.CHF15.threshold);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Can somebody explain why this is not working when in combination with cypress? Variable data.ctx is apparently there, but when using template/interpolating strings things stop working.
This is very confusing for me.
Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a ***typo*** - a leading space in the initial data.ctx.

Either

```js
if (data.ctx.trim() === 'cats')
```

or get rid of the space (why would you need it?)